# Why `#Preview(_:traits:_:body:)` is only available in iOS 17.0?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, preview

This question is not a `Code` question but I think it is related to the coding and programming and follows the StackOverflow guidelines.

I was using `#Preview` normally, but I needed to make the preview to fit to my view, so I did:

```
#Preview(traits: .sizeThatFitsLayout)
```

But I got:

> 'Preview(*:traits:*:body:)' is only available in iOS 17.0 or newer

As an [apple engineer suggested](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731865), I see I can use `PreviewProvider` to make it available for iOS 13 which is my target OS.

But this raises a couple of questions:

1. Isn't `#Preview` just another implementation of the `PreviewProvider` under the hood?
   1.1 If yse, so why it's not supporting older version.
   1.2 If no, why? Is there any issues with the original `PreviewProvider`?
2. Isn't `Preview` for Xcode? So why is it not running? Is Xcode depends on the iOS some how?

Comment: Please help me improve my question if needed 

Comment: Please have a look at https://www.avanderlee.com/xcode/preview-swiftui-uikit-appkit-views/

Comment: Thanks mr. @vadian. Im constantly reading good articles like this about the platform, but I'm struggling with these 3 questions even though I see the code that limits the API to iOS 17.

Comment: You need to distinguish between Xcode, Swift, iOS, and SwiftUI.

Comment: Did you read the article up to the *Can I use #Preview on iOS 16 and below* section?

Comment: Sorry mr. @matt I don't understand. I think Xcode shows the preview using Swift's macro to show the SwiftUI view that built for iOS platform. What am I missing?

Comment: @vadian Yes definitely. Actually the #Preview **can** be used on iOS 16 and below without passing parameters. This proves that Apple engineers are working on this to make this available. I just want to know is there any advantages against `PreviewProvider`? Should I just preview my work on iOS 17 target or convert my code to the older API. Thank you for following me up 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question *is* a code question. You are asking about a SwiftUI macro named `Preview` (See [Previews in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/previews-in-xcode)). Like any Swift API, the API was added at specific versions of the various OSes.

The older [`Preview(_:body:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/preview(_:body:)) was added as of iOS 13.0/macOS 10.15. But the newer [`Preview(_:traits:_:body:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/preview(_:traits:_:body:)) was added as of iOS 17.0/macOS 14.0. As you have seen, if your target's Base SDK is older than those, you get a warning such as:

> 'Preview(:traits::body:)' is only available in iOS 17.0 or newer

So while the `Preview` macro is being used by Xcode, it is still code written with Swift APIs and those APIs require a specific OS version for their availability.